# How to draw a HSV color wheel using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, hsv

is it possible to draw a HSV color wheel using matplotlib in python? I want to get an HSV color wheel like the following image as a reference image of the optical flow. In this image, every HSV color can be expressed as a vector where the direction is encoded in hue and length is encoded in saturation so that I can easily compare it with optical flow. I have searched online but I could not find a satisfied solution. Any help will be grateful!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following code uses [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) for the HSV to RGB conversion:

```py
def colour_wheel(samples=1024, clip_circle=True, method='Colour'):
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(-1, 1, samples), np.linspace(-1, 1, samples))

    S = np.sqrt(xx ** 2 + yy ** 2)    
    H = (np.arctan2(xx, yy) + np.pi) / (np.pi * 2)

    HSV = colour.utilities.tstack([H, S, np.ones(H.shape)])
    RGB = colour.HSV_to_RGB(HSV)

    if clip_circle == True:
        RGB[S > 1] = 0
        A = np.where(S > 1, 0, 1)
    else:
        A = np.ones(S.shape)

    if method.lower()== 'matplotlib':
        RGB = colour.utilities.orient(RGB, '90 CW')
    elif method.lower()== 'nuke':
        RGB = colour.utilities.orient(RGB, 'Flip')
        RGB = colour.utilities.orient(RGB, '90 CW')

    R, G, B = colour.utilities.tsplit(RGB)
    
    return colour.utilities.tstack([R, G, B, A])
```

[image: Colour Wheel]

We use it in this interactive Jupyter Notebook Matplotlib Widget:

[image: HSV Control Widget]

The repository is available here: https://github.com/colour-science/gamut-mapping-ramblings

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Kel Solaar is pretty good, but it doesn't actually use matplotlib.

Here's a similar result using `matplolib`, `numpy` and `coloursys`.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')

rho = np.linspace(0,1,100) # Radius of 1, distance from center to outer edge
phi = np.linspace(0, math.pi*2.,1000 ) # in radians, one full circle

RHO, PHI = np.meshgrid(rho,phi) # get every combination of rho and phi

h = (PHI-PHI.min()) / (PHI.max()-PHI.min()) # use angle to determine hue, normalized from 0-1
h = np.flip(h)        
s = RHO               # saturation is set as a function of radias
v = np.ones_like(RHO) # value is constant

# convert the np arrays to lists. This actually speeds up the colorsys call
h,s,v = h.flatten().tolist(), s.flatten().tolist(), v.flatten().tolist()
c = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x) for x in zip(h,s,v)]
c = np.array(c)

ax.scatter(PHI, RHO, c=c)
_ = ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

Note that this results in figure where blue/purple points upwards, while red points towards the right. In my experience, that's the typical optical flow hue plot. To achieve the image OP posted, change the following, so the figure starts drawing on the left instead of the right:

```
phi = np.linspace(math.pi, math.pi*3.,1000 ) # in radians, one full circle
```

[image]